# how to miniaturize whole screen?

Tags: html, jquery, css, screen

I have a webpage with some links .I wanted this links to miniaturize whole screen when I click on it.
actually I want resize screen to mobile screen size, but on same device! just like this webpage https://colorlib.com/preview/#major

in this webpage when you click on tablet link(on the right top of page),you see screen smaller. that is exactly what I  want! and I added all  js and css files of this site.

this is my html code:

```
<div class="tablet-btn header-btn pull-right hidden-xs visible" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
<a href="#" title="Tablet View" class="icon-tablet fa fa-tablet"></a>
</div>
```

and this is inner script code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
$("body").css({width:"800px"});


        })
    })
```

it miniaturizes body, but it doesn't include scrollbar!
I need to resize whole screen including the scrollbar

can you help me?

Comment: Put your "whole page" in a div and resize that

Comment: Try to add in css of the click overflow-y: scroll

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks but this approach deosn't include the scroll

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lks0adqj/ - can also apply the "tablet" style to the `body` - but I've not gone as far to determine what the minimum is (eg if you don't need the wrapper)

Comment: @MohcinBN it works .but now I have two scrollbars! I also can't set this property in css of body.